# problems with node js https on windows server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, https, iis-7

I'm trying to set up a node js application on windows server 2019 with iss7.

[Server setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xpxel.jpg)

That's the HTTPS express server setting on node js. When I'm browsing my webpage, there is an error message shown:

[thats the message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7sIO.jpg)

Some more information: I'm trying to build an application with react in the frontend and node js in the backend. It works fine on the local machine. It works also fine online, until I tried to post data via `axios.post()` I got

> mixed active content error

my website is running on HTTPS and the request is sent as HTTP. So I started to set up an express server running on HTTPS with the cert and private key file, which is used for the domain. I also changed the `axios.post` to HTTPS. Is there something wrong with my cert and key files or do I do basically a big mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Changing **HTTP** to **HTTPS** will solve this error.
You can add this meta Tag in the `<head>` section of your document:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

That meta tag will force the browser to replace insecure connections (`http`) with secured connections (`https`).